How to do a linear gradient which fades to transparent, not white, in CSS?
I have this as a gradient currently:
background: linear-gradient(
  to right,
  rgba(var(--white-rgb), 1) 0%,
  rgba(var(--white-rgb), 0) 100%
);

With this, on the left side it fades to pure white, and on the right it fades to transparent. If you have images paginating left, then what this looks like is this:

The image here is dark gray (it could be any image, this is just a placeholder), and the content background is different colors depending on where the paginating image scroller is used (in this case it's light gray, but could be green, red, blue, or other unknown colors). We originally had the background always be white, so fading to pure white made sense. But now it doesn't look right.
How can I say "fade the underlying content to transparent" on the left? Basically, start from transparent gradient on the right, then fade the background content to transparent on the left. Is something like that possible?
Otherwise, I might need to tell the gradient in every random case what the background color is to fade into, which will take some heavy refactoring probably, so wondering if I can avoid going down that road.
ChatGPT said to try this:
mask-image: linear-gradient(
  to right,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, /* Fully transparent on the left */
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100% /* Fully opaque on the right */
);

But that doesn't work, my DOM structure is something like this:
<div class="images">
  <div class="image-scroller">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="..."/>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="..."/>
    </div>
    <!-- more -->
  <div>
  <div class="paginate-left"></div>
  <div class="paginate-right"></div>
</div>

I would add that mask on paginate-left, but it doesn't apply to the <img> way beneath it seems.

You need a gradient mask. Check this existing question: Using CSS, can you apply a gradient mask to fade to the background over text?. If you believe your question is different from this one, please [edit] your post, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on the linked one are not helpful for your problem.

So, you don't want a linear gradient that has a transparent value, you want the image itself to become transparent in a gradient toward the edge of it's width?

Yeah I realize this is an unsolvable problem. Would need the browser to add some sort of mask-element: #my-image-scroller sort of CSS mask anchor thingy, so it only masked against a certain element. It masks against the whole coalesced DOM node stack under the paginate-left, etc.. So it fades to black :/

Solved by just passing the color the linear-gradient needs to use to match the background, even though it's ugly/messy. It works though. I did learn about mask-image though, which is great too.

The relatively new property mask-image mdn allows you to define an image whose alpha channel (opacity) would be used to mask the element it is applied to. This image can be a gradient.


body {
  background: green;
}

img {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  mask-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, transparent 100%);
}
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="an image">




Use the mask-image property with a linear-gradient containing an alpha channel.


body {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1072/800/300);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

img {
  mask-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(0 0 0 / 1) 50%, rgb(0 0 0 / 0) 75%);
}

p {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 150px;
  mask-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(0 0 0 / 1) 50%, rgb(0 0 0 / 0) 75%);
}
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/553/150">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus.</p>



